# Is there a way to make unique id per row on vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to VUE and I am wondering is there any way I can have a unique id per row with this kind of implementation

```
 <template slot="display" scope="row">
                <table-display>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </table-display>
                <table-display class="j-td-code">
                    <input type="text" v-model="row.data.code" />
                </table-display>
                <table-display class="j-td-name" value="">
                    <input  type="text" v-model="row.data.name"/>
                </table-display>
                <table-display >
                    <img :src="updateIcon">
                </table-display>
                <table-display >
                    <img :src="deleteIcon" @click="destroy(row.data)">
                </table-display>
            </template>
```

is a component and slotted on my parent component.

Hopefully someone could help me been working on this since yesterday.

Thanks! :)

Comment: I take it the component is being used in a `v-for`?

Comment: yep, the parent component has tr on v-for

Comment: You could pass an id as a prop and use `v-for="(obj, index) in list"` to pass the unique index/key to the component

Comment: yeah i am using that maybe i need to explainmy probem more.. So I have a main.js  in my main.js I have my parent component <datatable> on that same main.js file i am calling my second component <table-input>.. like this.. <datatable><table-display></table-display><table-display></table-display> </datatable>

Comment: I think you might. By id are you meaning the HTML attribute?